# Branch And Bound Implementation for TSP in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, traveling-salesman, branch-and-bound

I wonder if there is a useful Java implementation of a Branch And Bound algorithm for the TSP or in general a OR framework which includes a BnB for TSP.

Thanks for your help!

Marco

Answer (score 2):

BnB typically interacts with a *complete* sub-problem solver:

```
best_cost_soln_so_far = +inf
while (better_cost_soln = search_for_soln_cheaper_than(best_cost_soln_so_far))
{
    best_cost_soln_so_far = better_cost_soln
    backtrack_into_search
}
```

That is, your sub-problem search will backtrack whenever the cost of any partial solution it is exploring exceeds the bound set by `best_cost_soln_so_far`.  If the sub-problem search *does* find a better solution, `best_cost_soln_so_far` is updated, and the search continues from where it left off, looking for a still better solution.  It's pretty easy to implement.

That said, I doubt very much that you want to tackle large TSPs using complete search because of the huge search spaces involved; you may do better with approximate techniques such as simulated annealing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this pdf. Its very helpful and has details example and java implementaion for Branch and bound For TSP
[Here is the File Link](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_03/column7.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Although we all know that ["Java and Javascript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/471164), I would recommend looking at [SimplexJS](https://github.com/IainNZ/SimplexJS) which is a simple linear and MIP solver written in Javascript. Since it's small (less than 400 LOCs) it can be easily translated into Java. The author of the project also has a nice example of [Solving TSPs with Integer Programming](http://www.iaindunning.com/SimplexJS/ExTSP/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

OptaPlanner (open source, Java) has a Branch and Bound implementation. [See the docs section about BaB specifically.](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#branchAndBound) The implementation of the algorithm starts from [this class](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/exhaustivesearch/ExhaustiveSearchPhase.java), but that's hard to follow.

It also has a TSP example: although not configured with BaB by default, it's trivial to do so, by adjusting `tspSolverConfig.xml` like this:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <exhaustiveSearch>
    <exhaustiveSearchType>BRANCH_AND_BOUND</exhaustiveSearchType>
  </exhaustiveSearch>
</solver>
```

There are extra optional parameters to control node sorting, node exploration manner, etc.